# Get time between to peaks of a signal

Tags: ios, signals

all.

I need help, I have a signal like this one

```
                          /\
     /\                  /  \
    /  \      /\        /    \
0 ---------------------------------------
  /      \  /    \    /        \    /
          \/      \  /          \  /
                   \/            \/
```

and I need to detect all peaks (negative and positive). all values are float and I get all 66ms. I want to know time between two peaks. I need help to achieve it, I think I need to store all values in an array with timestamp from last peak, any one have best approach to do it ?

Thanks.

Comment: In what format do you have these values now?

Comment: Hi George, I get all these values from a loop, these values are float (0.3, 0.5, 2.4, ...)

Answer (score 0):

To discover a peak you might want to discover a change in direction.

You would not necessarily have to store the values in an array.

Pseudocode:

```
//every frame:
frameIncrement++;
currentDir = currentVal - prevVal
if( (prevDir < 0 && currentDir > 0) || (prevDir > 0 && currentDir < 0)) {
  //change in direction!
  time = frameIncrement * 66
  frameIncrement = 0
}

prevDir = currentDir
prevVal = currentVal
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi cantgetright82, thanks for your idea, I use a same approach to do that.